# How to merge two arrays with latitudes and longitudes to display markers?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Arrays to be merged**

```
var longitudeArray = [];
var latitudeArray = [];
```

I'm trying to merge the two arrays above to make a third array called `locations` to access it like the example below to display markers on Google Maps. Any ideas how to merge them both?

```
position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
```

Comment: _"Any ideas how to merge them both?"_ What is with your own ideas? What have you tried so far?

Comment: You'd want an array of arrays/multidimensional array.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-can-i-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript

Comment: I've tried the concat method but didn't work.

Comment: Then show your script and we can try to fix it. SO is not meant as a "write me a script"-service...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var locations = []
for (var i = 0; i < longitudeArray.length; i++) {
  locations[i] = [longitudeArray[i],latitudeArray[i]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function:

```
var latLng = latitudeArray.map(function(latitude, index){
    return [latitude, longtitudeArray[index]];
});
```

Comment: nice alternative to standard for :-)

Comment: @FlashThunder yeap :)